# What is this form of mass conservation equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

I found the following equation of conservation of mass (continuity) in "Computational Fluid Dynamics Vol.III" by Hoffmann:

$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\rho u)+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\rho v) + \frac{\alpha}{y}(\rho v) = 0$$

The author refers to Vol. II of the book for the origin of this equation, however, I don't have it.

So, has any one encountered this form of continuity equation? (regarding the $\frac{\alpha}{y}$ part of course) and what do those terms mean?.

Comment: Is this supposed to be universally valid or in a certain geometry?

Comment: @Bort Universally valid, the author used it to derive Reynolds average Navier Stokes equations (RANS) for two dimensional flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that this is done in cylindrical coordinates:
$$\partial_t \rho + \partial_x \rho u_x + \frac{1}{r}\partial_r r \rho u_r=0$$
Using the product rule the last term can be written as:
$$\frac{1}{r}\partial_r r \rho u_r=\partial_r \rho u_r + \frac{1}{r}\rho u_r$$

Update: The reference in vol. ii indicates that my feeling about this was correct. That term is introduced to allow planar flow for $\alpha=0$ (so normal continuity in Cartesian coordinates) and axisymmetric flow for $\alpha=1$ (hence the cylindrical coordinates). Some textbooks sacrifice clarity for brevity.

Comment: The equation is obviously in Cartesian coordinates!

Comment: Are you basing that solely on the use of x,y variables as cartesian coordinates? Because that is not the continuity equation in Cartesian coordinates. It wouldn't be the first textbook to redefine coordinates in an unconventional way.